# PHP Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null

Tags: php, mysqli

estoy teniendo un problema a la hora de consultar datos "Mysqli" me salta estos errores

```
PHP Notice:  Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\wamp\www\include\web\sub\betado_stats.php on line 115


<?php
    $dbHost = "127.0.0.1";
    $dbUSer = "root";
    $dbPass = "";
    $dbName = "test";

    $db = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUSer, $dbPass, $dbName);

    if($db->connect_error)
    {
        die('Error de Conexi&oacute;n: <strong>[ '.$db->connect_errno.' ] (<span style="color:red"> '.$db->connect_error.' </span>)</strong>');
    }

    $enc = $db->set_charset("utf8");

    $dbTable = "amx_bans";
    $query = $db->query('SELECT * FROM '.$dbTable) or die ("Error: ".mysqli_error($db));

    if(!isset($_GET['bid']))
    {
        $bid = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        $bid = $_GET['bid'];
    }

    $query = $db->query('SELECT * FROM '.$dbTable.' WHERE ('.$dbTable.'.bid = '.$bid.')') or die("Error en la consulta: " . mysqli_error($db));
    $betados = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
?>

<?php while ($betados = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) { ?>
<div class="betado_stats_info">
    <div class="user_info">
                    <div class="info_prim">
                        <div class="user_foto">
                            <img src="img/default_avatar.jpg" alt>
                        </div>
                    <div class="info_p">
                        <p class="p1">
                            Apodo :
                            <span>
                                <?php if($betados["bid"])
                                {
                                    echo substr($betados['player_nick'], 0, 15);
                                } ?>
                            </span>
                        </p>
                        <p class="p2">
                            Status :
                            <span>
                                <?php if($betados["bid"])
                                {
                                    echo $betados["player_id"];
                                } ?>
                            </span>
                        </p>
                        <p class="p1">
                            Perfil de Steam :
                            <a target="_blank" href="https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/<?php echo getSteam64($betados["player_id"]);?>">
                                <?php if($betados["bid"])
                                {
                                    ?>
                                    https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/<?php echo getSteam64($betados["player_id"]);
                                } ?>
                            </a>
                        </p>
                        <p class="p2">
                            Razón :
                            <span>
                                <?php if($betados["bid"])
                                {
                                    echo $betados["ban_reason"];
                                } ?>
                            </span>
                        </p>
                        <p class="p1">
                            Administrador :
                            <span>
                                <?php if($betados["bid"])
                                {
                                    echo $betados["admin_nick"];
                                } ?>
                            </span>
                        </p>
                        <p class="p2">
                            Fecha del Ban :
                            <span>
                                <?php if($betados["bid"])
                                {
                                    echo gmdate("d/m/Y - h:i A", ($betados["ban_created"]-14400));
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    echo gmdate("d/m/Y - h:i A", ($betados["ban_created"]-14400));
                                } ?>
                            </span>
                        </p>
                        <p class="p1">
                            Fecha de Expiración :
                            <span>
                                <?php if($betados["bid"])
                                {
                                    $diasBaneados = floor($betados["ban_length"] / 1440);
                                    $horasBaneadas = floor($betados["ban_length"] / 60);
                                    ?>
                                    <?php if($betados["ban_length"] == 0) 
                                    {
                                        ?>
                                        Nunca
                                    <?php }
                                    else if($betados["expired"] == 1)
                                    {
                                        ?>
                                        Expirado
                                    <?php }
                                    else if($betados["ban_length"] >= 1440)
                                    {
                                        ?>
                                        <?php echo "$diasBaneados" ?> días;
                                        <?php } 
                                    else if($betados["ban_length"] >= 60)
                                    {
                                        ?>
                                        <?php echo "$horasBaneadas" ?> hora;
                                    <?php }
                                    else if($betados["ban_length"] >= 5)
                                    {
                                        ?>
                                        <?php echo $betados["ban_length"] ?> minutos;
                                    <?php } 
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    ?>
                                    Nunca
                                <?php } ?>
                            </span>
                        </p>
                        <p class="p2">
                            Pov Demo :
                            <span>
                                <?php if($betados["bid"])
                                {

                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    ?>
                                    Sin demo
                                <?php } ?>
                            </span>
                        </p>
                        <p class="p1">
                            Math Hash :
                            <a>
                                <?php if($betados["bid"])
                                {

                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    ?>
                                    <span style=color:#999999;>No estaba en partido</span>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php }
```

Codigo actualizado con posiblemente la solucion al problema, lo que trato de hacer es que al yo darle click a un boton mas en especifico quiero que este muestre la informacion de la id al que yo le estoy dando click, en el codigo como lo tengo no me arroja ninguna consulta, que pasa y es lo que estoy viendo

$query = $db->query('SELECT * FROM '.$dbTable.' WHERE ('.$dbTable.'.bid = '.$bid.')') or die("Error en la consulta: " . mysqli_error($db));

mas especifico aqui

('.$dbTable.'.bid = '.$bid.')

lo que trato de hacer que al darle click al boton me arroje la informacion de dicho ID pero al darle click no me arroja nada no hace nada

antes de este codigo

esta este, esta este, esta este, esta este, esta este, esta este, esta

```
<?php
        $dbHost = "127.0.0.1";
        $dbUSer = "root";
        $dbPass = "";
        $dbName = "test";

        $db = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUSer, $dbPass, $dbName);

        if($db->connect_error)
        {
            die('Error de Conexi&oacute;n: <strong>[ '.$db->connect_errno.' ] (<span style="color:red"> '.$db->connect_error.' </span>)</strong>');
        }

        $enc = $db->set_charset("utf8");

        $dbTable = "amx_bans";
        $query = $db->query('SELECT * FROM '.$dbTable) or die ("Error: ".mysqli_error($db));

        $dbTable2 = "pug_serverstats";
        $query3 = $db->query('SELECT * FROM '.$dbTable2) or die ("Error: ".mysqli_error($db));

        $por_pagina = 15;
        $sql_register = mysqli_query($db, 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS registros FROM '.$dbTable.' WHERE 1');
        $result_register = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_register);
        $total_registros = $result_register['registros'];
        if(empty($_GET['pagina']))
        {
            $pagina = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            $pagina = $_GET['pagina'];
        }
        $desde = ($pagina - 1) * $por_pagina;
        $total_paginas = ceil($total_registros / $por_pagina);

        if(!isset($_GET['pug_index']))
        {
            $pug_index = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            $pug_index = $_GET['pug_index'];
        }

        $query = $db->query('SELECT server_name, bid, player_id, player_ip, ban_created, player_nick, admin_nick, admin_id, admin_ip, ban_reason, ban_length, expired  FROM '.$dbTable.' ORDER BY bid DESC LIMIT '.($pagina == 1 ? 0 : $desde).', '.($pagina == 1 ? 15 : $por_pagina)) or die ("Error en la consulta: ".mysqli_error($db));

        $query2 = $db->query('SELECT * FROM '.$dbTable.' WHERE 1') or die ("Error en la consulta: ".mysqli_error($db));
        $betados = mysqli_fetch_array($query2);

        $query3 = $db->query('SELECT * FROM '.$dbTable2.' WHERE ('.$dbTable2.'.pug_index = '.$pug_index.')') or die("Error en la consulta: " . mysqli_error($db));
        $pug_info = mysqli_fetch_array($query3);
    ?>
    <?php

    global $key;
    $key = '029014957D9D68624325AAF05259ECF5';

    // Con esta funcion obtienes la imagen el parametro $steamid supongo que lo sacas de la base de datos
    function getImagen($steamid)
    {
        if(strpos($steamid, ":"))
        {
            return getSteamImg($steamid);
        }
        return 'images/default_avatar.jpg';
    }

    function getSteamImg($steamid64)
    {
        $curl = curl_init();
        global $key;

        $steamid64 = getSteam64($steamid64);
        
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=$key&steamids=$steamid64&format=json",
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
        ));
        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        $json = json_decode($response, false);
        $avatar = $json->response->players[0]->avatarfull;
        return $avatar;
    }

    function getSteam64($steamid)
    {
        if(strpos($steamid, ":"))
        {
            $split = explode(":", $steamid); // STEAM_?:?:??????? format

            $x = substr($split[0], 6, 1);
            $y = $split[1];
            $z = $split[2];

            $steamid64 = $z;
            $steamid64 = $steamid64 * 2;
            $steamid64 = bcadd($steamid64, 61197960265728);

            if($y == 1)
            {
                $steamid64 = $steamid64 + 1;
            };
            $steamid64 = "765$steamid64";
            return $steamid64;
        }
    }
    ?>
    <div class="loader" style="display: block;">
        <div class="pag-default">
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="title_bans">
        <h1 class="title">
            <span class="icon-stats-dots"></span>
             Betados
        </h1>
        <a style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="ActualizarPag()" class="actualizar-button">
            <span class="ic-button icon-spinner11"></span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="comentarios">
        <p>
            "Los jugadores que se encuentran en esta lista son jugadores que fueron betados de la comunidad por un servidor o algun administrador por una razon, si fuiste baneado por un administrador debes subir tu <span>'POV DEMO'</span> a cualquier nube y enviar a un <span>'Fundador, Dueño o Socio'</span> luego de que la demo sea analizada segun el veredicto de la demo se aplica el desbaneo, de lo contrario el jugador no tendra derecho a un desbaneo en la comunidad"
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="betados">
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th class="thl thr" width="15%">Fecha </th>
                    <th class="thnone" width="5%"> </th>
                    <th class="thnone title_banlist" width="20%">
                        <span class="icon-user-tie"></span>
                         LISTA DE BANEADOS
                    </th>
                    <th class="thl" width="20%">Razón </th>
                    <th width="10%">Status </th>
                    <th width="15%">Fecha de Expiración</th>
                    <th class="thr" width="5%">Match </th>
                </tr>
                <?php
                while($top = $query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
                {
                    $diasBaneados = floor($top["ban_length"] / 1440);
                    $horasBaneadas = floor($top["ban_length"] / 60);
                    if(($top["bid"] % 2) == 0)
                    {
                        ?>
                        <tr onclick="DisplayBetado(<?php echo $top['bid']?>)" class="tr_2">
                            <td>
                                <?php echo gmdate("d/m/Y - h:i A", ($top["ban_created"] - 14400));?>
                            </td>
                            <td class="avatar">
                                <a target="_blank" href="https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/<?php echo getSteam64($top["player_id"]);?>">
                                    <img src="img/default_avatar.jpg" alt>
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            <td class="name">
                                <?php echo substr($top['player_nick'], 0, 15) ?>
                            </td>
                            <td><?php echo $top["ban_reason"] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $top["player_id"] ?></td>
                            <td>
                                <?php if($top["ban_length"] == 0) 
                                {
                                    ?>
                                    Nunca
                                <?php }
                                else if($top["expired"] == 1)
                                {
                                    ?>
                                    Expirado
                                <?php }
                                else if($top["ban_length"] >= 1440)
                                {
                                    ?>
                                    <?php echo "$diasBaneados" ?> días
                                <?php } 
                                else if($top["ban_length"] >= 60)
                                {
                                    ?>
                                    <?php echo "$horasBaneadas" ?> hora
                                <?php }
                                else if($top["ban_length"] >= 5)
                                {
                                    ?>
                                    <?php echo $top["ban_length"] ?> minutos
                                <?php } ?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <?php if($pug_info["pug_index"])
                                {
                                    ?>
                                    <a><?php echo $pug_info["pug_hash"] ?></a>
                                <?php }
                                else
                                {
                                    ?>
                                    <span style="color:#999999;">Sin demo</span>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php }
                    else
                    {
                        $diasBaneados = floor($top["ban_length"] / 1440);
                        $horasBaneadas = floor($top["ban_length"] / 60);
                        ?>
                        <tr onclick="DisplayBetado(<?php echo $top['bid']?>)" class="tr_1">
                            <td>
                                <?php echo gmdate("d/m/Y - h:i A", ($top["ban_created"]-14400));?>
                            </td>
                            <td class="avatar">
                                <a target="_blank" href="https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/<?php echo getSteam64($top["player_id"]);?>">
                                    <img src="img/default_avatar.jpg" alt>
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            <td class="name">
                                <?php echo substr($top['player_nick'], 0, 15) ?>
                            </td>
                            <td><?php echo $top["ban_reason"] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $top["player_id"] ?></td>
                            <td>
                                <?php if($top["ban_length"] == 0) 
                                {
                                    ?>
                                    Nunca
                                <?php }
                                else if($top["expired"] == 1)
                                {
                                    ?>
                                    Expirado
                                <?php }
                                else if($top["ban_length"] >= 1440)
                                {
                                    ?>
                                    <?php echo "$diasBaneados" ?> días
                                <?php } 
                                else if($top["ban_length"] >= 60)
                                {
                                    ?>
                                    <?php echo "$horasBaneadas" ?> hora
                                <?php }
                                else if($top["ban_length"] >= 5)
                                {
                                    ?>
                                    <?php echo $top["ban_length"] ?> minutos
                                <?php } ?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <?php if($pug_info["pug_hltv"])
                                {
                                    ?>
                                    <a><?php echo $pug_info["pug_hash"] ?></a>
                                <?php }
                                else
                                {
                                    ?>
                                    <span style="color:#999999;">Sin demo</span>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php }
                } ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div class="paginador">
            <ul>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(".loader").fadeOut("slow");
    </script>
```

y el .js es este

```
function DisplayBetado(val){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'include/web/sub/betado_stats.php?id=' + val,
        cache: false,
        success: function (html) {
            $("#betado_perfil").html(html);
            $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $("#betado_perfil").offset().top},500,function(){
                ultimoscroll=$(window).scrollTop();
                animacion=false;
            });
        }
    });
    return false;
};
```

cabe señalar que no me arroja ningun error que me diga el porque no muestra la informacion requerida a la hora de darle click para consultar espero que me puedan entender la verdad esto me esta matando la cabeza y mas si estoy aprendiendo js, si falta algo mas por favor avisarme

Answer (score 0):

Estas haciendo esto:

```
$query = $db->query('SELECT server_name, bid, player_id, player_ip, ban_created, player_nick, admin_nick, admin_id, admin_ip, ban_reason, ban_length, expired FROM '.$dbTable.' WHERE ('.$dbTable.'.bid = '.$bid.')') or die("Error en la consulta: " . mysqli_error($db));
$betados = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
```

Y no estás validando que $betados termine siendo cargado con algo.

El código menciona que la data es NULL, esto significa que no se cargo nada en $betados, lo que significa que si la query no falló, no se encontraron datos.

Primero comienza debugeando la query misma, para ver si trae datos. Puedes hacer un `var_dump($query)` y luego un `exit;` para imprimir el resultado, si dice NULL es que la consulta no te trajo datos.

Segundo,debes validar que la consulta te haya traido dichos datos. Si mal no recuerdo, `num_rows` valida cuantas filas de resultado has traido. Siempre deberia ser mayor a 0 para poder continuar, sino, no ha traido nada.

```
$query->num_rows
```

Comment: es que la tabla si tiene datos, hice esta misma funcion para mostrar otro dato y funciono perfectamente pero aqui es la excepción

Comment: Pero haz lo que te digo, no estas validando el momento en que la consulta falle por X motivo...

Comment: Listo, que pasa en la consulta estoy agg ('.$dbTable.'.bid = '.$bid.'), en esta parte    $query = $db->query('SELECT * FROM '.$dbTable.' WHERE ('.$dbTable.'.bid = '.$bid.')') or die("Error en la consulta: " . mysqli_error($db)); si yo llego a quitar la parte donde esta el bid este si me muestra los datos pero que pasa yo hago eso es para yo poder consultar los datos de una id solamente ya que si lo quito me apareceran todas las consultas pero tengo un problema al agg la parted de bid en la tabla no me aparece nada queda en blanco

Comment: Lo que trato de hacer en si es que al momento de yo darle click a un digamos para consultar los datos de una persona solo me muestre los datos de esa id no el de los demas

Comment: Agrega eso a tu publicacion para entender mejor de que hablas

Comment: Listo ya actualice la publicacion

Comment: ayuda pls me esta matando esta vaina